# Просуммировать ячейки в многостраничной таблице

Tags: jquery

Имеется многостраничная таблица (вывод по 10 строк на страницу), необходимо просуммировать значения по ячейкам .sum на странице и вывести сумму в ячейку #summary внизу страницы:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    calculateSum();
});

function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".sum").each(function() {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });
    $("#summary").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

Проблема состоит в том, что при перелистывании страниц сумма не меняется. Помогите решить.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте такой скрипт:

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  calculateSum();
});
```

`#btn` - Кнопка которая переключает страницы вашей таблицы

Comment: Теперь сумма меняется, но при смене страницы показывает сумму по предыдущей странице.

Comment: @Den38, Вставьте `calculateSum()` в конце функции которая загружает следующую страницу вашей таблицы